# Парсинг с помощью simple_html_dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, веб-скрейпинг

Всем привет! Помогите в вопросе...
Есть страница, на ней есть данная таблица:

```
<table class="tablesorter tablesorter-default" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" role="grid">
<thead>...</thead>
<tbody aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
    <tr role="row">
        <td> <strong><a title="Bread" href="http://site.com/Bread/">Bread</a></strong> 
        <br>
        <img class="tie-appear" 
                src="http://url-at-image/Bread.png" 
                alt="Wheat" 
                width="100" 
                height="100" 
                data-image-key="Bread.png" 
                data-image-name="Bread.png">
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2 min</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <a title="Bread" href="http://site.com/wheat/">Bread</a>
        </td>
        <td>Bakery</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
```

Нужно пройтись по таблице->найти и выбрать необходимую информацию->занести в массив.
Парсинг выполняю этим кодом:

```
require_once 'lib/SimpleHtmlDom.php';
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$url = 'http://site.com/table.html';
$html->load_file($url);
$articles = array();

foreach ($html->find('table tbody tr') as $article){ 
    $item['name'] = $article->find('td strong a', 0)->innertext;
    $item['image_url'] = $article->find('td img', 0)->src;
    $item['image_name'] = $article->find('[data-image-name]', 0);
    $articles[] = $item; 
}

//output
print_r($articles);
```

На выходе получаю это:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bread
            [image_url] => http://url-at-image/Bread.png
            [image_name] => 
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Other
            [image_url] => http://url-at-image/Other.png
            [image_name] => 
        )
    ...
)
```

**Суть вопроса:** как получить значение `image_name`? т.е. как правильно прописать поиск чтобы вытянуть значение атрибута `data-image-name`?

Comment: а почему вы думаете, что получение значения атрибута `src` как-то отличается от получения атрибута `data-image-name` ?

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо, ответ я уже нашёл:

```
$item['image_name'] = $article->find('img', 0)->attr['data-image-name'];
```